# External connection from SSH

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, remote-access

I installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 the openssh-server and wanted to access my pc remotely through the terminal of other networks, such as the university, for example, but I'm only able to access through ssh when on the same network.

If someone can help me establish this external connection so I can access my pc while on another connection I would be very grateful.

I do not use a router, other than the one provided by Vivo (Router / mode Vivo Fibra).

NOTE: I do not intend to use putty, Team Viewer or anything, I just want to use the terminal, for me it's more practical.

I do not have fluence on English, sorry for this. Text translated by google.

Comment: This is the page of port forwarding on the router [https://i.imgur.com/yiX9hKt.png], but I dont know where I need to put the IP of my machine/router and the protocol that I need to use

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Instead of doing it as a comment, it is usually better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1355270/edit) your question when adding information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the external `ip address`, you can do that with https://www.whatismyip.com/ ....

You have to setup your `ssh server`, mainly your port.... set your port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to something other than `22`......then do

`service ssh restart`....

You have to have a username to use in the ssh command that you have permission to log into.....

You have to allow `ssh` in your `iptables`......like this:

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport PORT -j ACCEPT`.....

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT:

Do this↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ to add new port for ssh remember `PORT` in the command should be the port that you choose as maybe `34503`

```
root@ubuntu:/# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport PORT --jump ACCEPT
root@ubuntu:/# iptables-save
```

end of edit

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

You have to be sure there is open through your router..... portforwarding the service ssh for the port you've chosen.....

You can also set ssh keys like here......https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh.......

then there is the command itself:

```
ssh -p PORT USER@EXTERNAL-IP
```

when you connect answer `yes` to the question if you trust the new connection..... and your all set, good luck

Comment: How can I allow this `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport PORT -j ACCEPT`

Comment: why make things harder throuh changing port? makes things little bit more complicated and wont add any security

Comment: @Gustavo if you can access ssh from another PC in same network it means that you do not need to use iptables. However, if you already changed port and restarted sshd then it is possible that new port is closed. I'd say do not change ssh port.

Comment: I can access from other PC on the same network, but I need to access outside this network

Comment: @GustavoLuizBispodosSantos I've updated my answer good luck

Comment: @GustavoLuizBispodosSantos there are alot of `how to's` on portforwarding on the web, use google, search for your router and ssh portforwarding

Comment: Solved with this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072129/external-connection-from-ssh#1072141

Comment: @GustavoLuizBispodosSantos cool that's great to hear, thanks for accepting

Comment: @GustavoLuizBispodosSantos please upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a public IP address then you need to know the public IP address, which is dynamic.  If your PC is on the same domain as your Ubuntu server, then you can use the domain name instead of the IP address. Ex:

```
ssh user@subdomain.domainname.org
```